# AS3 - Hindi font half letters getting converted

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, hindi

I have some text in Hindi language that should appear as क्या appears as क् या (without the space) which is not the way I want.

I am embedding fonts, but however flash is auto converting the "half letters". These sentences are getting read from an XML (which is UTF-8 encoded) and being directly applied into the textfield. In Flash Professional it shows up fine but when I check it in the app it appears as above. Anything that I am missing out on here?

Here is the textfield settings in my code:

`tf.multiline = true;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;`

Comment: Consider using [TLFTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html) instead of the classic TextField.

Comment: Will try this and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLFTextField is the way to go.  I had to convert all of my text fields in an application to TLFTextFields in order to show international characters.  A TLFTextField is much larger in size then a regular TextField.  You will notice when you compile the swf that it will grow quite large if you have many TLFTextField's.